# Feature request: Improve user profile page interface

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, stackexchange.com, network-profile

There isn't any *Edit Profile* button on one's Stack Exchange user page when the profile was copied from another Stack Exchange page. This is very perplexing because no hint of the underlying cause is offered. The 'Update Profile Info' button merely opens a prompt to copy the profile from a particular site and feels like an error.

The interface should indicate from where the current profile was last copied, and the button should be more clearly labelled "Import profile info".

The import dialog should highlight the last-used site and those sites that actually have a profile to copy from.

A preview or undo facility would be nice.